# Sharepoint Calculated

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns, sharepoint-designer

I need some help. I have created three columns. The first column is where the "DATE" displayed, second column is where I've inputted the 4 string characters (ex. WASF) and the third column is where I the concatenated 4 strings (in 2nd column) and the last 2 digits in year ( first column - ex. 2016 => 16) are being displayed. The third column will look like this. **WASF16**.

My problem is if the first column which is the date (specifically in year) changed it shouldn't affect the third column. Is this possible? or do you have any suggestion or solution for this?

Hope to hear from expert of sharepoint!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
=CONCATENATE(SecondTXT,RIGHT(YEAR(OrderDate),LEN(YEAR(OrderDate))-2))
```

[image]

Comment: But what if I updated the year under "OrderDate" for example I changed it to 2019. It should not affect the column "cal2". Does it make sense?

Hope to hear you soon

Comment: For this case, use field static name as field static name won't change. You could get field static name by REST api /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist2')/fields

Comment: Where should I find this "REST api /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist2')/fields" in sharepoint designer 2013? Sorry I am new to sharepoint I"m not familiar to this one.

Comment: Browse the request in browser, http://server:port//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist2')/fields, disable rss feed in IE, Internet options->content->Feeds and Web Slices->settings->uncheck 'Turn on feed reading view'

Comment: How can I make a static field in this one for example:http://teams.test.com/sites/ToolsProcesses/mpl_test_area/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BEFBA23DC%2DD4E7%2D4D1A%2DBE77%2DF7495688F64D%7D&Field=Work%5Fx0020%5FOrder

The column is Work Order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflow instead of calculated column.

1. change your third column to text data type & make it optional
2. in SharePoint designer,create a workflow to run only when an item is inserted in list
3. in workflow,from action, choose "set a field in current item"
4. set "field" to third column & set "value" to your desired string(with help of string builder)
5. save and publish workflow, test it by add new item to your list!